# How can I detect whether a tag found by BeautifulSoup.find_all is the first/last tag in the searched string?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a function in python to process HTML content, that works differently on tables from other tags. The main purpose is that I want to convert content with pypandoc from html into markdown, but converting tables never seems to work. So I want to keep the tables in HTML form while converting the rest.

For example, I want this:

```html
<h3>RRRRRRRRRRRRRR</h3>
<p> Xxxxxxxxxxx II jj</p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

to convert to:

```markdown
### RRRRRRRRRRRRRR
Xxxxxxxxxxx II jj

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I wrote the function below to generalize to any tag or find_all search string. However, it does not work if the found tag is the last in the searched HTML code. I would like to set a condition to detect such cases. What is the best way of detecting whether `item` is the last or first item in the soup?

Or, alternately: is there a better way of processing everything except the tables?

```py
def do_nothing(input):
    return input

def process_tags_differently(tag_to_process, doc_contents, process_tag=do_nothing, process_out_of_tag=do_nothing):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc_contents, "html.parser")
    list_of_tags = soup.find_all(tag_to_process)
    if(len (list_of_tags) > 0):
        for item in list_of_tags:
            split_contents = doc_contents.split(str(item))  # doc_contents split in 3: before, item, after
            part1 = process_out_of_tag(split_contents[0] )
            part2 = str(item)
            ret = part1 + part2
            print(len(split_contents))
            # this part is recursive, to process the rest of the file
            if(len(split_contents) > 1):
                part3 = process_tags_differently(tag_to_process, split_contents[1], process_tag, process_out_of_tag)
                ret = ret + part3
            return ret
    else:
        # no more tags found, process the rest of the doc
        return process_out_of_tag (doc_contents)
```

Here's an example of a test that failed:

```py
    dc1 = "<h1>xxxxxx</h1><p>aaaa</p><img src='toto.htm'/>"
    result = process_tags_differently('img', dc1, double_str)
    good_result = "<p>aaaa</p><img src='toto.htm'/><img src='toto.htm'/>"
```

The result was:

```
process_tags_differently('img', dc1) failed! 
was 
<h1>xxxxxx</h1><p>aaaa</p><img src='toto.htm'/><img src="toto.htm"/>, 
should be 
<h1>xxxxxx</h1><p>aaaa</p><img src='toto.htm'/>
```

Comment: `soup.select` let you use css selectors. in your case `:last-of-type` or `:last-child` could be of use

Answer (score 0):

I opted for a solution that is much less clever, more boring, and specific to the task.

In the code below, I use BeautifulSoup to replace each table with a paragraph that will never occur in the content, namely `<p>&&& ïïï ùùù</p>`. I then convert the lot to markdown, then put the tables back into the content.

```py
import constants as c
import pypandoc
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    md = open(f"{c.OUTPUT_PATH}/a_test.md" , 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc_contents , "html.parser" )
    tables = soup.findAll("table")
    divider = soup.find("p", {"id": "__divider__"})
    for table in tables:
        parent_table = table.findParent("table")
        if table.parent_table is None:
            print("found table!!!, table.findParent('table')= "+ str (parent_table))
            divider =BeautifulSoup("<p id='__divider__'>&&& ïïï ùùù</p>" , "html.parser" )
            table.replaceWith(divider)
    cont = str (soup )
    cont = convert_snippet(cont)

    for table in tables:
        cont = cont.replace('&&& ïïï ùùù',  str(table), 1)
    output=doc_header + cont
    print(output)
    md.write(doc_header + cont)

def convert_snippet(txt):
    ret =  pypandoc.convert_text (
    txt, 
    'md', 
    format='html',
    extra_args=[ '-s', '--wrap=preserve']
    ) 
    return ret

doc_header=""" 
{
    "title": "A test",
    "linkTitle": "A test",
    "weight": "1"
}
"""


doc_contents="""
<div>
<h3>RRRRRRRRRRRRRR</h3>
<p> Xxxxxxxxxxx II jj</p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p> Xxxxxxxxxxx II jj</p>
<p> Xxxxxxxxxxx II jj</p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>BBBBB</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>BBBBB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BBBBB</td>
<td>AAAAA</td>
<td>BBBBB</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```